# VLC view 4k video on a 1080p monitor

Tags: vlc-media-player

I see that VLC 3.0 now supports hardware decoding of 4k video.

I have a 4k video shot on my drone. I am trying to view it on a 1080p monitor. Obviously, VLC resizes the window to fill my monitor so I am effectively viewing the video at 1080p.

What I want is to be able to view the video in its native resolution, i.e. at 4k. I realise that this means I'll only be able to see a portion of the video as my screen isn't big or dense enough. Thus I need VLC to be able to zoom in.

Is this possible?

Comment: There is a zoom option in VLC under Show all settings -> Video.

Comment: If you're on Linux, you can use `xrandr` to give yourself a 4K desktop and pan around it with the cursor keys.

Comment: Does your GPU support it?

Answer (score 2):

> [Unfundednut's
>   comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1295637/vlc-view-4k-video-on-a-1080p-monitor/1295643#comment1920345_1295637)
>   that "There is a zoom option in VLC under Show all settings -> Video"

That's a valid answer but he left it as a comment. So, I'm going to attempt to answer how to do it without zooming and keep it at exactly it's native resolution.

Under `effects` there's you can tile the video. The usage was intended for EX: if you have four 1080p monitors you could make a patched together 4k monitor out of them. However, you could use this effect to see your video at it's native resolution if you tell VLC to tile your 4K video 4 times.

Because 4k divided by 2 (if your 4K is 3840 × 2160) equals 1080p

---

You need to check what 4k you really have though because 4k can mean:

- 3840 × 2160
- 3840 × 1600
- 4096 × 2160
- 4096 × 1716
- 3996 × 2160

So do the math first.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better option.
Go to Tools -> Effects and Filters -> Video Effects -> Geometry -> Interactive Zoom and enable it.
It will display a small window with full reso video (zoomed out) in the top-left corner with ability to choose the area to display.

Comment: Hi Anton, I guess you're using VLC on Windows? What you've described sounds exactly like what I see on a Mac, as I wrote in my answer a year ago https://superuser.com/a/1295816/12653

Comment: No, I'm on Linux. I think you don't want to change system resolution or use other system tools like Magnification. This is feature of VLC and it works great. The only issue with it, is that it is hidden so deeply. I wish it would be somewhere in "Video->Zoom" vlc's menu.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that I'm on a Mac, but @Unfundednut's comment about the zoom feature was exactly what I needed. On a Mac it's under

```
Window -> Video Effects -> Geometry -> Magnification/Zoom
```